# Deleting cookie in array by key

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I'm trying to delete a cookie that is in the products[] array. The adding-part works perfectly, the deleting not so much.

```
 $prd = "product_" . $_POST['productId'];

 if($f['archive'] == "N"){
 //Adding the cookie -- works perfectly

      setcookie("products[$prd]", "active", $expire); 
 }else{
 //Deleting the cookie -- doesn't work

      $cookie_items = $_COOKIE['products'];
      setcookie($cookie_items[$prd], "", time()-3600);
 }
```

The array inside the cookie works perfectly, so it has to be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used this `$cookie_items[$prd]` to unset cookie You are getting the value of the cookie, to unset you need to use the key of it again like when you set:

```
setcookie("products[$prd]", "", time()-3600);
```